# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could somebody please check my solution?

I want to check, whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^2}$ converges or diverges.

Using the Comparison test:

Let $a_n = \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^2},~ b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^2} \frac{n^2}{1} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$.

Since $0<e<\infty$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: It does work, but wasn't is simpler to notice that
$$
0\leq \frac{(1+\frac1n)^n}{n^2}\leq \frac{e}{n^2} \text?
$$

Comment: It is correct. Nice work.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: Good and simple answer.

Comment: I do not see why someone would want to add the word limit in front of the comparison test? I think one should respect the OP's language/notation

Comment: @Lost1 The comparison test (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComparisonTest.html) is completely different from the limit comparison test (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitComparisonTest.html).

Comment: @TylerClark fine, have it your way... I still think you should leave it alone. It is better if you add a comment so the OP knows. Also they might have been taught it under a different name. Also the comparison also actually works here... The sequence (1+1/n) to the n is bounded above. Maybe that is what he should have done

Comment: @TylerClark google comparison test and on wikipedia, it can be used to mean either of the things wolfram alpha defined.

Comment: @Lost1 When going to the Wikipedia page for the Direct Comparison Test, you see that the first sentence is "In mathematics, the comparison test, sometimes called the direct comparison test to distinguish it from similar related tests (especially the limit comparison test),..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct. However, the simpler trick implied by the problem is to notice the numerator. Recall that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e
$$
Since all the terms are positive, we have 
$$
0\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e}{n^2}= e \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
By the $p$-test, the series on the right converges. Therefore, your original series converges.

**EDIT** As suggested by user21820, it might be unclear what I was saying. The limit just produces me a number, $e$ to use to bound the original series. The solution 'works' because $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<e$ for any positive integer $n$. This is usually discussed when one learns the definition of $e$. So then each term on the right sum is larger than that of corresponding ones in the original. The use of $e$ was arbitrary (but suggested by the numerator). We could have used 'any' number, $\pi, e^2,4,10,\sqrt{17}$, so long as $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ was smaller than our choice of number, say $x$, for all positive integer $n$ (or at least all but finitely many of them). Then we would have written
$$
0\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{n^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n^2}= x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
for whatever larger number we chose.

Comment: Hmm did you forget to mention that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<e$ for any positive integer $n$? If you just use the limit being $e$, you need to ignore a finite number of terms and add in some little epsilon somewhere.

Comment: @user21820 You don't need to ignore any number of terms, we aren't looking at partial sums in my answer. Instead, we are looking at the series as a whole. Moreover, even when looking at a finite number of terms, as you point out, $\left(1+1/n\right)^n<e$ for any positive integer $n$. Because of this, $e$ in the numerator is larger than $(1+1/n)^n$ for any positive integer $n$ in the numerator. Hence, even when looking at partial sums, the series on the right in my answer is always larger than the partial sums of the original series. No epsilon argument or ignoring terms needed.

Comment: No in your answer you stated the limit of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ to be $e$, but that does not give what you want without using what I described. Instead you need the actual inequality as I said.

Comment: @user21820 I believe you are confused. I use the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$ is $e$. Since $e>(1+1/n)^n$ for all positive integer $n$, $e/n^2>(1+1/n)^n/n^2$ for all positive integer $n$. Then whether you are looking at partial sums or the series as a whole, you have the required inequality. I'm not trying to show that in the limit the original sequence becomes 'like' $\sum e/n^2$. Rather, I'm just finding something bigger to bound the original series by. I could have equally used $\sum e^2/n^2$ or $\sum 4/n^2$ or $\sum \pi/n^2$.

Comment: That is why I said you should have mentioned the inequality because it was nowhere in your answer, and readers might get the incorrect impression that the limit is enough to justify your later bounding. The second part of my first comment was to say that you could indeed do with just the limit, except that you need more work. I mentioned that because in some cases we don't have a strict inequality like we do in this case, but the alternative technique remains valid.

Comment: @user21820 What works/doesn't work in other cases is immaterial. I merely answered the question as written. In this problem, every partial sum satisfies the inequality as does the original series. The answer is correct and sufficient as it stands. The question is in how detailed it need be. Should the OP have been confused about what I had done, they could have asked. If you don't care for my solutions level of detail, that is perfectly valid. Not every mathematician proof writes the same way. Feel free to provide your own solution with the level of detail you like to see.The OP might benefit!

Comment: I agree that it is fine to omit details if you think they are simple enough, but my point is that the statement you had about the limit is irrelevant to the solution if you are just using the inequality, so it is simply misleading. It would be good if you just state the inequality instead of the limit.

Comment: We differ in terms of what we think students would think is elementary. But indeed, better to err on the side of caution. I shall quickly add this as an edit note to be as clear as possible to the OP. Thank you for your input. It is always helpful to be critiqued to better help students in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Using the limit comparison test, 
$$ {1\over n^2}\left(1 + {1\over n}\right)^n \sim {e\over n^2},$$
your series converges.